# Javascript ES6 classes: how to send an event from one class to another

Tags: javascript, class, events

The structure of my code is like a hub and spoke model, with most of my classes instantiated in a Main class that is the hub. In particular, I have a zoom method in the Main class that coordinates calling zoom methods in most of the other classes. In one of the spoke classes, let's call it Buttons, I create some buttons intended to trigger the zoom method in Main, with event listeners added. How might I use these buttons, created in Buttons, to call the zoom method in Main without importing all of Main into Buttons?

Main.js looks something like this:

```
import Header from './Header.js';
import ImageStrip from './ImageStrip.js';
import AreaChart from './AreaChart.js';
import Buttons from './Buttons.js';

class Main {
  constructor() {
    this.header = new Header();
    this.imageStrip = new ImageStrip();
    this.areaChart = new AreaChart();
    this.buttons = new Buttons();
  }

  zoom(scale) {
    this.imageStrip.zoom(scale);
    this.areaChart.zoom(scale);
  }
}
```

Buttons.js looks something like this:

```
class Buttons {
  constructor() {
    const els = document.querySelectorAll('.buttons');
    this.makeButtons(els);
    }

  makeButtons(buttons) {
    buttons.forEach((button) => {
      button.addEventListener('click', () => {
        ? call the zoom method in Main ?
      })
  })
}

export default Buttons;
```

Comment: Seems like an X Y problem to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that you're not really listening for an event, you just want to call a method, you should just pass the instance of `Main` to the constructor of `Button`.

This is called dependency injection.

Answer (score -1):

```
Change Buttons class like this

class Buttons extends Main {
  constructor() {
    super();
    const els = document.querySelectorAll('.buttons');
    this.makeButtons(els);
    }

  makeButtons(buttons) {
    buttons.forEach((button) => {
      button.addEventListener('click', () => {
        super.zoom();
      })
  })
}
```

Comment: That still requires importing Main while giving you the disadvantage of inheritance for no benefit

Comment: This does not mean this approach is wrong. There is no disadvantage of inheritance unless you are reusing code. Well if you have better solution present then.

Comment: You mean that there's no advantage unless you're reusing code right?